# C# Listbox.DrawItem to color each lines

Tags: c#, listbox

I have some code to change how listbox act. I can change the color of text, but I am unable to change the color of the background of each line.

This is in a for loop for every of my lines

LBLines is an array of string store in a global variable

```
if (LBLines[e.Index] != "None")
{
       e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.FromName(LBLines[e.Index])),
e.Bounds.X,e.Bounds.Y,e.Bounds.Width,e.Bounds.Height);
}
```

This will color EVERY lines of the same color, even those listed as "None", thou what I need is that they stay same color as default background color.

EDIT: Comparaison is not the problem, problem come from the e.Graphics.FillRectangle. It seems to color ALL the lines spaces, regardless of the one I am drawing.

EDIT2: Modified code to show that h was equal to e.Index

Comment: I would check to make sure you're doing a correct compare on LBLines[h] != "None" first`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard to say without more context around your code (the loop, the method,...), but this code does what I think it is you want:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string[] Colors { get; set; }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Colors = new string[] { "red", "blue", "white", "none", "orange" };
        listBox1.Items.AddRange(Colors);
    }

    private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        e.DrawBackground();
        if (Colors[e.Index] != "none")
        {
            using (var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromName(Colors[e.Index])))
            {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, e.Bounds);
            }
        }
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Colors[e.Index], Font, SystemBrushes.ControlText, e.Bounds);
    }
}
```

Note that the `DrawStyle` property of the `ListBox` is set to `OwnerDrawFixed`.

Comment: Yeah, I removed loop but it didnt fix the thing.

Comment: No, it seems background does it for ALL the lines. That's weird because DrawString work just fine.

Comment: This is what I have as code (except for var names) and it doesnt work.

Comment: Ok, I made ONE change. The only difference between your code and mine was that I set all the bounds one by one, while you, you just used e.bounds. I changed that and now it works... wtf?

Comment: Strange - mine works even if I change it to explicitly describing the rectangle like you did (as I would expect) - but I'm glad you got it to work now :-)