# C# listbox's element color

Tags: c#, listbox

I want to change the line of each color of the text in Listbox in c# is there any method in listbox I search and I find some thing like this

```
e.Graphics.DrawString(myListBox.Items[i].ToString(), myFont, myBrush, e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
```

Is there another way which does not use `e.Graphics`

Comment: Simple answer: **No**

Comment: maybe duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119196/c-sharp-listbox-drawitem-to-color-each-lines

Comment: What's the problem with `e.Graphics` approach ?

Comment: In fact you can use `Win32 functions` to do it directly but that would be more complicated than just use `e.Graphics`. So the answer is No.

Comment: Yes.  You should **always** use TextRenderer.  DrawString was a 12 year old mistake, fixed 8 years ago.